# Chapter name in [oneside]{scrbook}

Tags: chapters

In {scrbook} class the chapter begun just with the number of a chapter :

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Default Chapter Heading}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to have in regular way like this:
[image]

without changing `\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}` and without using `{fncychap}`

Any help with this please! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable `chapterprefix`:

```
\documentclass[oneside,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries} % not sans serif
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Default Chapter Heading}
\end{document}
```

[image]